# Python / XPOST via requests doesn't work while curl is working well

Tags: python, curl

When Im running curl locally, everything is working as expected:

```
curl -XPOST http://myserver:8080/api/ -d '{"id":"1","message":"TEST","from":1008003880,"to":1008003881}'
```

Im writing python code, in the following way:

```
// some code
import requests
// some code
data_input={"from":t_before, "to": t, "message": "TEST-2", "id": "1"}
print data_input
r = requests.post(url="http://myserver:8080/api/", data=data_input)
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

It gives the following output:

```
{'to': 1008003881, 'message': 'TEST-2', 'from': 1008003880, 'id': 1}
(400, 'Bad Request')
```

What can be the reason? is python change the request in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of requests are you using? Could be that you need to json encode your data.

Use json.dumps() to encode your data:

```
import requests
import json

data_input={"from":t, "to": t, "message": "TEST-2", "id": "1"}
print data_input
r = requests.post(url="http://myserver:8080/api/", data=json.dumps(data_input))
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```